# JADE: difference between for and each

Tags: javascript, pug

Why is there a difference between

```
- for(var user in users) {
  p= user //output: user1
- };
```

and

```
each user in users
  p= user //output: [object Object]
```

according to http://jade-lang.com, they are aliasses, so why do they have a different output ?

List of users (JSON-format)

```
users = {
    "user1": {
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Doe"
    },
    "user2": {
        "firstname": "Jane",
        "lastname": "Roe"
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with the hyphen, but I'm not sure

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ: in de documentation of http://jade-lang.com, they are saying that for and each are aliasses, but I think I solved it (see my answer underneath) Is my answer correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a solution that works, I had to use `value, index` otherwise an object was returned

```
each value, index in users
  li= index //output: user1
```

Answer (score 0):

They do the same thing, but `for` is the javascript's way to do it and `each` is jade's way.

In Jade, you can put a `-` and start writing javascript, `for` or `while` or whatever.

On the other hand, jade knows the keyword `each` and on the background translates it to a loop for you.

It's a little different because `each user in users` translates to something like

```
for (var key in users) {
    var user = users[key];
    // the rest of the code
```

So, in this case, `user` would be the object, not just the key, as javascript's `for` iterates over the keys in the object.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, at least if you're right (because someone down voted your answer)

Comment: I *am* right. You can test it yourself on jade-lang.com and see. I don't know why someone would down-vote this :)

Comment: another question: my teacher used this loop:  each user in users.list
but I don't know how to use users.list, it keeps giving errors

Comment: This doesn't address the core issue, which is that `for` and `each` are aliases, but the `for` being used in the question is **not Jade's `for`**, but javascript's.

Comment: I do not have problems with the for loop, but with the each loop, I would like to get the index of the JSON object in the each loop, and I think my answer underneath solved this

Comment: @NickSpriet I just wanted to give you an idea why they are different. It's up to you how you want to utilize them in your project.

Comment: Yes, this made it more clear, thank you responding on my question ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not using Jade's `for`, but Javascript's.

The following is equivalent to your `each` version:

```
for user in users
  p= user
```

In your case, because of the `-`, you were using Javascript's own version of `for`, which iterates over the *keys* of an object and not over its values.

Comment: You can't write it like that.. it gives the following error: `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: @NickSpriet Seems it only works on arrays. Where did you read they were aliases? I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/ it's the last sentence in the `each chapter` (I made printscreen for you: http://prntscr.com/9i8h68)

Comment: and my users list is a JSON-object

Comment: @NickSpriet It's working perfectly for me here at least: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjLRVM

Comment: Thank you for the working example, strange... I did EXACTLY the same thing :p